# JClouds working with VolumeAPI from org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaAPI

Tags: openstack-nova, jclouds

org.jclouds.openstack.nova.v2_0.NovaApi provides direct access to ServerApi, FlavorApi and ImageApi. I was expecting VolumeApi also to be available from NovaApi but observe it is missing. Please let me know how to list all Volume details using JCloud

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because all those APIs are exposed by OpenStack Nova itself. In jclouds, you can access the volume API by using the [Cinder API](http://jclouds-javadocs.elasticbeanstalk.com/org/jclouds/openstack/cinder/v1/CinderApi.html).